# Integration by Partial Fractions: Numerator Should Be One Degree Lower than Denominator

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

At 1:36:13 (on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJGp0pyPoVo&list=PLDesaqWTN6EQ2J4vgsN1HyBeRADEh4Cw-&index=11), the professor says:

> Whatever factor you have, your numerator should be one degree lower than that. So for linears, one degree lower than a linear is a constant. One degree lower than a quadratic is a linear.

However, this doesn't seem to hold true in some of the worked examples in Stewart's Early Transcendentals (8th Edition) where you have:

$$\frac{x^3-x+1}{x^2(x-1)^3} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2} + \frac{C}{x-1} + \frac{D}{(x-1)^2} + \frac{E}{(x-1)^3}$$

Another example shows:

$$\frac{4x}{(x-1)^2(x+1)} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{(x-1)^2} + \frac{C}{x+1}$$

With D and E in the first equation, and B in the second equation being constants, don't these examples disprove the statement above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just an alternative way of writing it, since

$$\frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2} = \frac{Ax + B}{x^2}$$

and the polynomial $Ax+B$ is one degree lower than $x^2$.

---

If the polynomial isn't $x^n$, then the constants change a little, since

$$\frac{C}{x-1} + \frac{D}{(x-1)^2} + \frac{E}{(x-1)^3} = \frac{C(x-1)^2 + D(x-1) + E}{(x-1)^3} = \frac{C'x^2 + D'x + E'}{(x-1)^3}$$

for some constants $C', D', E'$, so it's sort of up to you. You can either go calculate $C,D,E$ or $C',D',E'$.

Answer (score 0):

The exact formulation is that the degree of the numerator should be lower than the degree of the `irreducible factor` in the denominator, not than the degree of the denominator itself.

And it is not necessarily lower by $1$: if the degree of the irreducible factor in the denominator is $d$, the degree of the numerator is *at most* $d-1$.